# If a square wave is a sum of odd harmonic impulses, why is it continuous in the frequency domain?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-domain

A square wave is a sum of sinusoids so surely it should be represented as individual discrete impulses in the frequency domain, where all other frequencies are 0. Why instead are those intermediate frequency components not 0, and form a continuous sinc shape? I know that the continuous fourier transform of $A\text{rect}(\frac{t}{\tau}) = A\tau \text{sinc}(f\pi\tau)$, but why is this the case when you think about it in the first perspective?

Comment: Discrete vs continuous?  They are not interchangeable.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by continuous? Do you mean continuous vs discrete or continuous as in the smoothness of the derivatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Hilmar mentioned I think you get confused between Square wave and  Rectangular function.

In [Wikipedia about Square Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave) :

> A square wave is a non-sinusoidal periodic waveform in which the
> amplitude alternates at a steady frequency between fixed minimum and
> maximum values, with the same duration at minimum and maximum.

[image]

Which its Fourier Transform is only at harmonic frequencies and its value is equal to Fourier series coefficient.

but [Rectangular Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function):

> The rectangular functionis defined as:

[image]

which look like this:

[image]

and its Fourier Transform is a sinc function that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Oh yes of course

Comment: But the impulses are in the shape of a sinc nonetheless. I found this similar question: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/why-fourier-series-and-transform-of-a-square-wave-are-different

Comment: @m-sh-shokouhi The Fourier Transform of a periodic square wave is not a stream of impulses as you show in the second figure.Those impulses would be weighted by the Sinc function, resulting in odd harmonics for a 50% duty cycle square wave since the even harmonics will fall in the nulls of the Sinc.

Comment: @DanBoschen I agree with you. I will correct it.

Answer (score 5):

A square wave is not a Sinc function in the frequency domain, but a sampled Sinc function (Even as a continuous function, the non-zero values are samples of the Sinc function in frequency). An individual rectangular pulse is a continuous Sinc function. The difference is the former is repeating in time. Repetition in one domain relates to sampling in the other domain.

This property holds for any repeating pattern. The envelope will be the Fourier Transform of the base shape, and then when repeating, non-zero frequency values will only exist at integer multiples of the repetition rate. This is demonstrated with two variants of a repeating pulse below, the first with a 50% duty cycle and the second with a 25% duty cycle.
The pulse has a Fourier Transform as a Sinc function with the first nulls at $1/T$ where T is the pulse width (in this case 0.05 seconds and 0.025 seconds), while the pulse is repeating at a 10 Hz rate in both cases. The red trace is the Fourier Transform of the pulse (a Sinc) while the impulses shown are the non-zero frequency components.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't a single pulse just a square wave modulated with a rect on that particular pulse.. so it would be a sinc convolved at every harmonic.. I'm not managing to get to the stage where its just a single sinc with infinite amount of samples in the frequency domain

Comment: @LewisKelsey When you repeat anything it MUST be discrete in frequency; a continuous frequency spectrum can’t exist (unless you allow zero values). This is clear by studying the Fourier Series Expansion where it is clear that you can’t possibly reconstruct the signal, and have it repeat, unless every harmonic similarly repeats over that cycle. So this propery can be carried to any fundamental shape — the transform will have the envelope of that shape but the frequencies can only exist (as non-zero values) at harmonics of the repetition rate

Comment: https://structural-analyser.com/domains/DE/Fourier_transform/ this allowed me to finally see what was going on

Comment: @LewisKelsey Very good-- yes you can see here how each tone required for reconstruction is an integer multiple of the repetition rate...and importantly as we decrease the repetition rate (for that same basic shape), the tones in frequency get closer and closer, until ultimately at the extreme where we don't repeat for infinite time the frequency response becomes a continuous function!--- but in all cases it is mapping out the same basic shape of the Fourier Transform of that base pulse. This was the basic point of my answer here.

Comment: I discovered also an important axiom, multiplication with a tighter impulse train in the frequency domain results in a more sparse convolution in the time domain

Comment: @Lewis Also not sure if this helps you or not but you can completely swap the domains which sometimes provides more intuition. For example, if you are familiar with sampling in time (A/D and D/A conversion) and how that creates periodicity in frequency: it's the same exact relationship so more generally Sampling in one domain is Periodicity in the other domain.

Comment: well I am stuck on one thing. usually in the frequency domain you can plot it if it's real, i.e you're plotting frequency and the real axes. you can get a square wave then intuitively by doing $-\cos{2\pi t} + \frac{1}{3} \cos(6\pi t) - \frac{1}{5} \cos(10\pi t) $ anything below the horizontal axis in the frequency domain then has 180° phase. But what about the regular case of $\sin(2\pi t) +\frac {1}{3}\sin (6\pi t)... $. It's imaginary and I can only see how you get the amplitude and phase spectrums separately but I don't understand the diagram you sent which shows the impulse

Comment: .. below the horizontal axis. So I'm not sure what the sinc envelope represents in this case and why it's not drawn separately as amplitude and phase. My thought was it could be an imaginary frequency plot but I can only get negative I values  $\frac{1}{2i} \delta(x-a)$

Comment: Yes in this case if the time domain waveform is symmetric about 0 (non causal) the phase will only be 0 and 180 in frequency (frequency will only be real) but in general cases it would be complex in which case we would plot magnitude (all positive) and phase separately. If you haven’t already I think it would be instructive for you to work out the Fourier Series Expansion of sich a repeating pulse (start with a square wave to see how you only get the odd harmonics). Do the reconstruction from the harmonica back to time manually to see how the square wave gets reconstructed—

Comment: Then try any other frequency in the reconstruction to see how that possibly can’t work and it should all be clearer. Also keep in mind that the Fourier Series Expansion of a waveform over finite time 0 to T (or -T/2 to +T/2) is identical to the infinite duration waveform with that original waveform periodically repeating in time. Doing this exercise I suggest will make that clearer too

Comment: I've had a look at it and I've managed to calculate how the complex fourier series becomes the fourier transform as T→∞ and how you get the complex fourier series from the $a_n$ and $b_n$ fourier series. I'm still unsure how to explain intuitively why the complex part of the frequency domain disappears and becomes a real sinc when you use the complex fourier series compared to the $a_n$ and $b_n$ fourier series which must have imaginary parts because the result contains $\sin$s in the summation. If you transformed this summation using the fourier transform wouldn't you get an imaginary part?

Comment: @LewisKelsey excellent. That last part is simply because the function is symmetric about zero on the time axis--- any real function that is symmetric MUST be real in the other domain. Similarly any real function that is assymetric (such as -1 for t<0 and +1 for t>0) MUST be imaginary in the other domain. For this reason causal functions must be complex since a causal function is the addition of a symmetric and asymmetric function. Cool, huh?

Comment: If you want to know why this is true work through the math but a GREAT example is Euler's formula for sine and cosine (both real functions!). What are they in the frequency domain? Symmetric/assymetric real/complex?

Comment: oh I thought of something intuitive. That link I sent im guessing shows an imaginary part because their square wave is not an even function. When you have an even function its components must ultimately be of real phase (0 or $\pi$). For instance $-\cos(x - \frac{3}{4}\pi) -\sin(x - \frac{3}{4}\pi) \equiv 1.414\cos(x)$. So that particular $\sin x$ sequence will not be part of the even pulse. I found this https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/340/ft_symmetry.php and pretty sure at the bottom they mean 'if the input function is real and *even*' and 'even *(Re(x))* and an odd (sin(x))'

Comment: @Lewis This may help you, in particular the bottom graphic summarizing those relationships:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68063/zero-phase-shift-filters-must-be-symmetric-about-the-origin/68064#68064

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by "square wave".

A single rectangular pulse has indeed a sinc spectrum

An infinitely repeating series of rectangular pulses has a line spectrum with discrete frequencies